# Installing a specific plugin version for PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, github, phonegap-plugins

The latest version of this plugin does not work when I build my PhoneGap app:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

So I want to go back to version 0.6.3, which I know works:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/v0.6.3

However when I run:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/v0.6.3
```

I get:

```
[phonegap] adding the plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/dc894c1eeede69b935f19891fda8e45a6c4e8f2f
[error] Fetching plugin failed: Error: Command failed: fatal: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/dc894c1eeede69b935f19891fda8e45a6c4e8f2f/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep the .git url then concat #VERSION.

In your case :

`phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git#v0.6.3`

Answer (score 0):

you could just download the desired version to a local folder and then use the path of that local folder in your `phonegap local plugin add` call.